# get facebook user email and user first/last name with Phonegap FB Plugin for IOS app

Tags: javascript, ios, facebook, cordova

Working on my first phonegap ios app.
Trying to incorporate this plugin https://github.com/Wizcorp/phonegap-facebook-plugin/tree/master/platforms/ios/www

Basically I just need to alert the users email and first/last name, although I'm a bit stuck on how to do so using this plugin.

What I wanted to do was retrieve that information, then pre populate some forms to create a new user to use with Parse.

I'm able to get a response from this function that displays a status and an authResponse with tokens and the user ID:

```
           var login = function () {
            if (!window.cordova) {
                var appId = prompt("Enter FB Application ID", "");
                facebookConnectPlugin.browserInit(appId);
            }
            facebookConnectPlugin.login( ["email"], 
                function (response) { alert(JSON.stringify(response)) },
                function (response) { alert(JSON.stringify(response)) });
        }
```

I'm just unsure in terms of next steps on how to go about retrieving the users email and first/lastname..and whther or not I have to dig deeper into facebooks API.

any help is appreciated.

*** UPDATED ***

Figured it out.  I was missing a step that i found over at the facebook api page

```
         var login = function() {
         if (!window.cordova) {
             facebookConnectPlugin.browserInit('APPID');
             facebookConnectPlugin.browserInit(appId);
         }
         facebookConnectPlugin.login(["email"], function(response) {
             if (response.authResponse) {
                 facebookConnectPlugin.api('/me', null,
                     function(response) {
                         alert('Good to see you, ' +
                             response.email + response.name + '.');
                     });

             }
         });
     }
```

Comment: I realize this is an old post, but thank you for taking the time to post the answer after you figured it out. Here in 2017 the documentation seems a bit lacking.

Comment: But these days you need '/me?scope=email' instead of just '/me'

Comment: @DiamondDrake of course. Hopefully it was helpful. Documentation is always changing...I remember I did a fair amount of digging for the solution when this happened. And good to know on the scope parameter.

Answer (score 0):

Try this plugin(http://plugins.cordova.io/#/package/com.ccsoft.plugin.cordovafacebook) this covers all of your needs.