# Correct use of the cordova-plugin-facebook4 api method

Tags: javascript, facebook-graph-api, phonegap-build

(For what it's worth; I had this working, but for iOS compatibility, I've had to switch plugins)

Hopefully, this will be the last time I ask on this subject.  I'm now using the following [plugin](https://github.com/jeduan/cordova-plugin-facebook4) for **phonegap build**:

`<gap:plugin name="cordova-plugin-facebook4" source="npm">`

For what it counts, on this version of the CLI:

`<preference name="phonegap-version" value="cli-5.2.0" />`

My login works fine, but it doesn't run the callback for the `api` function:

```
var fbLoginSuccess = function (response) {
    alert ("success");
    storage.setItem("user_auth",response.authResponse.accessToken);     //get access token
    user_auth = response.authResponse.accessToken;

    login_data.auth_token       = response.authResponse.accessToken;    //get access token
    login_data.account_id       = response.authResponse.userID;         //get facebookConnectPlugin UID
    login_data.expires          = response.authResponse.expiresIn;      //get expire duration   
    login_data.socialmedia_name = 'facebook';

    facebookConnectPlugin.api("/v2.3/me/?fields=id,email,first_name,last_name",["public_profile","email"], function(profileData) {
            alert ("api success");
            login_data.email        = profileData.email; 
            login_data.display_name = profileData.first_name + " " + profileData.last_name;
            //...
        });
}

var fb_login = function() {
    var login_data = {};

    client.cmd          = "login";
    login_data.userid   = user_id;
    login_data.cmd      = "login";

    facebookConnectPlugin.login([
                'public_profile',
                'email',
                'user_posts',
                'user_photos',
                'user_videos',
                'user_friends'
    ], fbLoginSuccess,
                function (error) {
                    console.error(error); 
                }
    );
}
```

I've followed the guidance from [this link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25961817/get-facebook-user-email-and-user-first-last-name-with-phonegap-fb-plugin-for-ios) to have another attempt like this:

```
var fbLoginSuccess = function (response) {
    storage.setItem("user_auth",response.authResponse.accessToken);     //get access token
    user_auth = response.authResponse.accessToken;

    login_data.auth_token       = response.authResponse.accessToken;    //get access token
    login_data.account_id       = response.authResponse.userID;         //get facebookConnectPlugin UID
    login_data.expires          = response.authResponse.expiresIn;      //get expire duration   
    login_data.socialmedia_name = 'facebook';

    facebookConnectPlugin.api("/me",null,function(profileData) {
        alert ("api success");
        login_data.email        = profileData.email; 
        login_data.display_name = profileData.first_name + " " + profileData.last_name;
        //...
    });
}
```

But no luck - I'm surely missing something very simple - what is it?

Comment: Hi there, same situation here. How did you resolve?